# Path.GetTempFileName in MultiProcessing

Tags: c#, multiprocessing

we run several instances of our program (c#) on a single computer.
In each instance our code tries to create "many" temporary files with help of method Path.GetTempFile().
And sometimes, our program fails with exception:

```
Exception: Access to the path is denied.
StackTrace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
```

I checked temporary folder and didn't find something strange: free disk is enough, number of temporary files is not very big, etc.

I have only one explanation: one instance gets temporary file and opens it, but in the same time, another instance also gets name of the temporary file and tries to open it.
If it is correct?
If yes, how to solve the issue, if not how to understand what a problem?

**UPD:**
failed on computer with **Windows Server 2008 HPC**

Thank you,
Igor.

Comment: Not likely I think. If the `GetTempFileName` method weren't thread-safe or didn't generate a well-randomised name, it wouldn't be there. Not that I know what the exact cause is...

Comment: To eliminate what you think could be the cause, just do a *if (Directory.Exists(myTempFolderName))* before you create the temp folder - if it exists then generate a new name.

Comment: You mean, it is not good practice to use Path.GetTempFileName()?
If the method not "multi thread or process save" how we can use it?

when I need temporary folder with a special extension, I use Guid for generation unique file name.

Comment: It is an operating system problem, you'll need to document which one you are using.  If it is Windows 7: yes, it has cooties.

Comment: failed on computer with Windows Server 2008 HPC

Comment: I believe GetTempFileName just calls the Win32 equivalent so I would expect it to the same or similar between OS versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982613/en-us

Answer (score 6):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) states for the `Path` class:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe.

[Furthermore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) there are two reasons given for IO exceptions:

1. The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if it is used to create more than 65535 files without deleting previous temporary files.
2. The GetTempFileName method will raise an IOException if no unique temporary file name is available. To resolve this error, delete all unneeded temporary files.

I'd recommend to check for this conditions (since you explicitly state that you create *many* temp files).

Comment: I checked windows temporary folder. I didn't find more than 1000 files in the folder. "Many" in our case it means maybe 200-300 temporary files (totally) when all instances start to work.

As I understand "thread safe" is not equivalent to "multi process save". we have several instances (processes, not threads).